# Rendering multiple/dynamic widgets based on a list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I am trying to build dynamic widget(cards, blocks, containers with some properties) based on a list of items(entries). Trying to create a function for that(I don't need to create a separate class for that right?).

```
  List entries = ['stock1', 'stock2', 'stock3'];

  Widget buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: entries.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
          );
        });
  }
```

And then I am trying to call that function and add to my body to the list of the widget so it builds all the widget automatically(and I don't have to create them one by one manually).

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: 20.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              child: Text('Hello. This is a Container')), //Container
          buildListView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've also read somewhere you can utilize `.map()` method somehow if it's relevant here?

How do I make it work? Please share solutions/ideas or helpful sources/links about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it:

```
Column(
   children: [
        for(final entry in entries)
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Center(child: Text(entry)),
          ),
        ],
),
```

Or if you wish to use map, you need to add toList() in the end:

```
entries.map((entry) => Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: Center(child: Text(entry)),
          ),
          ).toList(),
```

[Read article on this](https://nashwaay.medium.com/simplest-way-to-render-widgets-from-a-list-in-flutter-3bbb6e53a8c3)